# How can I block NetCut in my network?

Tags: networking, internet-connection, arp

I am facing a huge problem in my shared network. We are almost 30 users sharing a single internet connection.

Someone is using [NetCut](http://www.arcai.com/netcut-faq/62-what-is-netcut.html) and taking all the bandwidth from us. Not allowing even to send e-mails. This is frustrating.

Is there any way to protect my computer from NetCut? Is there any way to block the use of NetCut at the router?

Comment: Do you _know_ they are using NetCut specifically?  Who's the network administrator? What kind of routers?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Is this a wireless or wired network? More details, please

Comment: I don't have the administrative rights. I know they are using `NetCut` because I saw them using and I downloaded `NetCut` and `NetCut Defender` it shows how many users are using `NetCut`. If somebody using it then there is column in this software called protected by netcut and the value is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the people who wrote NetCut also wrote something called [NetCut-Defender](http://www.arcai.com/netcut-defender-faq/item/98-netcut-defender.html) which protects from NetCut itself.

Comment: They claim that it will protect from NetCut but sorry to say it doesn't work in protecting. I did some research before asking this question. I tried using some software to change my IP didn't work even.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using this tool in an academic or corporate network (and most other networks) would face disciplinary sanctions. Talking to the network administrator would be the best thing to do.

To immune yourself to it, you would probably need to setup a static arp entry for the router, block all broadcast traffic you send, and send gratuitous ARPs to the router as unicast (frequently). Probably all that after having changed your MAC address. Even then, if the "attacker" managed to poison the forwarding table of the switch you're connected to, your MAC address may leak to it.

You could also counter-attack or use the same tool as him, but you would be liable to the same sanctions as he does.

Comment: Counter Attacking helps before asking this question I started counter attacking. Good suggestion but what exactly I can do without having the administrative rights? Is there any tools which can protect my system form ARP?

Answer (score 0):

How can I block NetCut in my network?

I know its subject very old

and am sory for my bad english

I hope that I will benefit and benefit from you more

abut test in my router

Dlink DSL-2750u irmware Version:ME_1.16

and its work for block sarching ip and mac addris

i do this on my setting router

1-Enable MultiAP Isolation [on]

and

2-User Isolation [on]

this 2 options important

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.